# Prevent scroll when calling update()

Tags: chart.js

I have multiple charts on a page, contained within Bootstrap collapsible divs. Each chart is dynamic, meaning that actions the user takes can cause the chart to be updated. The issue I'm seeing is that after each call to update(), the scroll position of the page returns to the top.

I've tried a suggestion I read in another question, to store the current scroll position before calling update and resetting it after the update call, but that does not work.

Here's the current sequence I'm trying:

```
let pos = $(document).scrollTop();
this.chart.update();
console.log(`Setting scroll to: ${pos}, window.scrollY = ${window.scrollY}`);
$(document).scrollTop(pos);
```

That logs the following in the console:

```
Setting scroll to: 968, window.scrollY = 968
```

However the window still scrolls back to the top of the page. I checked the Chart.js docs for events to see if there was a after update event I could use to set the scroll position instead, but the only events listed are related to touch / mouse events.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Argh. The problem was with the dropdown select having an 'href="#"' tag that wasn't needed, it just needed the onclick event.